# How can I solve an index out of range error?

Tags: c#

I hava a combo box that contains students from a studentList. When I select a student it should populate a text field of the students name. Whenever a student is selected from the combo box I get the following error

```
ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
```

I think the problem may be in my loop but I'm having trouble finding out how to fix the error, any help would be appreciated

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < Main.studentList.Count; i++)
    {
        if (comboBox1.SelectedItem == Main.studentList[i].StudentName + " " + Main.studentList[i].StudentId)
        {                  
            break;
        }
    }

    txtName.Text = Main.studentList[i].StudentName; //where the error occurs
}

public void ChangeStudent_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //loading combobox from studentList
    foreach (var student in Main.studentList)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(student.StudentName + " " + student.StudentId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging the application? Put a break point on the line where your error is occurring - then check the value of `i`.

Comment: You are using your loop variable (`i`) outside of the loop. That is rarely a good idea. What value do you think `i` have _after_ the loop?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason it's throwing an error is after the break, i gets incremented. If i was the last item in the list, it's now out of bounds. If it wasn't, it's now pointing to the next item.

The simple solution would be to move the line that is throwing the error above the break;

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < Main.studentList.Count; i++)
    {
        if (comboBox1.SelectedItem == Main.studentList[i].StudentName + " " + Main.studentList[i].StudentId)
        {                  
            txtName.Text = Main.studentList[i].StudentName; 
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, consider using a foreach loop. Here's the exact same logic with a foreach loop. It makes it a bit more readable.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var student in Main.studentList)
    {
        if (comboBox1.SelectedItem == student.StudentName + " " + student.StudentId)
        {                  
            txtName.Text = student.StudentName; 
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The error occurs because on the last loop in the for loop `i` is incremented by 1:

```
i++
```

It then evaluates to false in the expression:

```
i < Main.studentList.Count
```

So when you get to the line where the error occurs `I` is equal to  `Main.studentList.Count` and so an index out of range error occurs.

If you want to access the last element of the list you can do:

```
Main.studentList[Main.studentList.Count - 1].StudentName
```

Alternatively if you want to evaluate the statement on each loop just move it inside of your for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Main.studentList.Count; i++)
{
    if (comboBox1.SelectedItem == Main.studentList[i].StudentName + " " + Main.studentList[i].StudentId)
    {
        txtName.Text = Main.studentList[i].StudentName;            
        break;
    }
}
```

This also has the advantage of keeping the variable `i` local to the scope of the loop.

Answer (score 3):

Change your code like that and please try again

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < Main.studentList.Count; i++)
    {
        if (comboBox1.SelectedItem == Main.studentList[i].StudentName + " " + Main.studentList[i].StudentId)
        {              
            txtName.Text = Main.studentList[i].StudentName; 
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same variable(i) for range calculation and also assignment.
Try this.

```
 private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int j;
            for (int i = 0; i < Main.studentList.Count; i++)
            {
                if (comboBox1.SelectedItem == Main.studentList[i].StudentName + " " + Main.studentList[i].StudentId)
                {  
    j=i;                
                    break;
                }

            }

            txtName.Text = Main.studentList[j].StudentName; //where the error occurs

        }

        public void ChangeStudent_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //loading combobox from studentList
            foreach (var student in Main.studentList)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(student.StudentName + " " + student.StudentId);

            }
        }
```

Comment: What happens if no match was found? It no longer throws an exception, but is the behavior now correct? What happens if the students list is empty?